# How do I reorder google results after search? I want to create an extension that can reorder the results of a google search

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension, google-search

I am trying to create an extention that can reorder google results if I search for something like "how to make a paper airplane". Right now I just want to be able to change 2 link's orders. For example my current code

```
var xpath = function(xpathToExecute){
  var result = [];
  var nodesSnapshot = document.evaluate(xpathToExecute, document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null );
  for ( var i=0 ; i < nodesSnapshot.snapshotLength; i++ ){
    result.push( nodesSnapshot.snapshotItem(i) );
  }
  return result;
}

var xps = xpath('//*[@id="rso"]/div')

finalDivs = []

for (var i = 0; i < xps.length; i += 1 ) {
    if (xps[i].className == 'g' || xps[i].className == 'hlcw0c') {
        finalDivs.push(xps[i])
    }
}
```

This allows me to obtain an object with all relevant div tags. I can then assign each div to a ranking by creating another object, but I am unsure how I can then reorder the search results based on these results. Is there a way to reinject the div order back into the webpage I am on? The code I am currently using is put into the sources tab like this:

[image: Where code is being run]

Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: a noble cause no doubt